# Covariance between two regression coefficients

Tags: regression, covariance

For a regression y = a*X1 + b*X2 + c*Age + ... in which X1 and X2 are two levels (other than the base) of a categorical variable. Age is a continuous variable.
The estimated coefficients, a_hat, b_hat and c_hat, are all significant and positive.
I calculated the variance/covariance matrix of the regression and noticed that
cov(a_hat, c_hat) is positive but cov(b_hat, c_hat) is negative. Will that be possible? Or did I do something wrong?
I also saw the similar thing in an more advanced regression that includes the interaction terms of those variables.
Thanks.